# How to upgrade Android app from official version to test version

Tags: android, testing, google-play-console

I currently use the inner sharing of the play console to release new versions to testers. (They have exactly the same package name and signing key.)

However, the testers responded that they could not upgrade from the official version to the test version, so the app update process could not be tested.

If I install the app first and open the inner sharing link, the play store displays

***"A public version of this app is already installed on this device. Uninstall it and try again"***

Is there a way to upgrade directly from the official version to the test version in the play store like installing an apk? (not uninstall app)

For example, the internal test of the play console may be possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is missing a bit of important information. What are the `versionCode`s of the official and test versions of the app? Do both versions have the same exact package name? Were they signed with the same signing key?

Comment: thanks for your reminder,
They have exactly the same package name and signing key.
The versionCode of the test version tends to be the same as the official version to be released.
 I was using the apk format, and because I had to switch to the bundle release, I encountered the problem of installing the test version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using internal app sharing https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing/ to share your app, then it won't work. Internal app sharing is used to quickly share an app with your internal team and testers, it doesn't undergo google play review process.
So you can't update your public version using this.

You can however, use different play console tracks for uploading your apps and they will support updates. Here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en is the link for setting up open closed or internal track. When you upload your app to any of these tracks, they'll go through the google review process and once the app is available on playstore, testers can easily update it.

In case you don't want to wait for review, and want to use `internal-app-sharing` only, then, you can create 2 different versions of your app(different version numbers) and upload both of them to `internal-app-sharing`. You can then share the 2 links to your testers, and your testers should first install the lower version app and then open up the link of higher version number apk. It'll show the update button.

**Edited(Thanks to @[pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265103/pierre)):** *Although it looks like you're uploading artifacts signed with the same key, the Play Console actually re-signs the artifacts in the `internal-app-sharing` to avoid distributing an app signed with the production key that hasn't gone through their review process.*

Comment: This is correct. I'll add that, although it looks like you're uploading artifacts signed with the same key, the Play Console actually re-signs the artifacts in the internal app sharing to avoid distributing an app signed with the production key that hasn't gone through their review process.

Comment: Thanks, these suggestions help a lot.
However, considering that the version number change will cause too many problems, it is not suitable for internal testing at this time.

I have considered using "firebase distribution" instead, but it seems to be the same as "internal-app-sharing", which will cause sgin test key to fail to update.

We are still discussing solutions. Currently we tend to maintain apk testing, but update the version with bundles.